# Re-overriding elements in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

If you have overridden elements from the A-Master in several pages, is there any way of reconnecting them if you change your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-applying the Master Page to the page in question will swap out any Overridden objects that have not been modified. Any objects that have been modified will stay on the page and the master page items get placed behind.

The easiest way to apply a master page is probably to just drag the master page icon in the Pages Panel to the page below that you wish to apply it to.

You can also right click the page and select "Apply Master To Pages..."